# Access: Unrecognized database format error .mdb

Tags: database, ms-access

I have an access database which has been working fine for years but of sudden I have started getting the unrecognized database format error while opening the tables, queries etc. I have tried compacting and repairing and it worked but it keeps giving me this error on a daily basis. Everytime I take the previous backup, update it with the latest data, it starts running but after a while it stops running.

I have no other solutions left. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you give us more information about what happened? Did you upgrade your access version?

Comment: no, I have been accessing it through access 2007 since long time, but this is a 2003 format

Comment: I also do not know why but when I open one of the tables I see a lot of ############# as separate line items. Is this a possible corruption

Comment: Is the `.mdb` file on a shared folder? Is someone else opening it at the same time as you?

Comment: Please respond to the comment from @Yawar - it is important.